# Jasypt: Encrypt Multiple Passwords in Configuration File

Tags: java, spring, encryption, jasypt

I've seen multiple tutorials that explain using Jaspyt with Spring explaining how to encrypt a property value, but they always use only one value!

What if I have two or more passwords that I want to encrypt?

Here's what I have so far.  How do I have multiple encrypted properties with Jasypt?

Tomcat setenv.sh to set system properties

```
1 CATALINA_OPTS="-Dtarget_env=local"
2 CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -DpwdOne=MY_PWD_ONE"
3 CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -DpwdTwo=MY_PWD_TWO"
4 ...
```

Spring ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <!-- Passowrd encryption HOW TO ADD MULTIPLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORDS???-->
    <bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
        <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
        <property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="pwdOne" />
??????pwdTwo??????
    </bean>
    <encryption:string-encryptor config-bean="environmentVariablesConfiguration" id="stringEnc"/>
```

I used the encrypt executable to create the hash:

```
./encrypt.sh input=pwdOne password=MY_PWD_ONE
```

...And used the result in my application.properties

```
com.mycompany.pwdOne = ENC(xJ9TBHNUiiidDlng3MCBjA==)
```

...But what about other properties?

```
com.mycompany.pwdTwo = ...
```

Comment: Have you found a method that worked for you?

Comment: Any idea how is can be done?